Why does VNC server fail to start desktop environment with an “Session cleanly exited too early” error?
I’m having trouble launching the desktop environment for noVNC. After setting up and trying to run the VNC server, I receive the following error:
root@localhost:~# vncserver :2
New Xtigervnc server 'localhost:2 (root)' on port 5902 for display :2.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.okGWtL/passwd :2 to connect to the VNC server.

=================== tail /root/.vnc/localhost:2.log ===================
Session startup via '/root/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!
Maybe try something simple first, e.g., tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited! Killing Xtigervnc process ID 16190... success!
root@localhost:~#

Only the default tigervncserver works. I’ve tried different desktop environments, including XFCE, GNOME, and others, but nothing seems to work. The session always exits too early.
